# how to associate phone number to a callback task in twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-flex, twilio-taskrouter

I was able to create a callback task but its not associating the phone number with it which in turn doesnt show the callback button in twilio flex panel.

here is the api used:
https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/workspaceId/Tasks

here is the payload sent.

```
task channel: callback,
workflowsid : "",
attributes: {}
```

so is it possible to create a callback task with phone number associated to it?

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible to create a callback flow in Twilio Flex/Taskrouter. There are a few things you need to do though.

1. You would create a task as a "callback" task type.
2. When you create the task you need to write the task attributes like to and from to that task.
3. Then you need a Flex plugin which when `afterAccept` of callback tasks triggers an outbound call to the "to" number of that task. This can be done using Twilio Flex Actions and Event Listeners. See [the documentation.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/actions)

If you are looking for something pre-built, then there are a few partner solutions like [Ciptex Race](https://www.ciptex.com/race) that have this functionality out of the box which sits on top of your Twilio Flex.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions recently, but please abstain from adding boilerplate like greetings or signatures - answers should focus strictly on actually answering the question.

Comment: @tripleee I can point out many examples where Twilio Evangelists have started an answer with "Twilio Evangelist Here!" I believe that is done to add context and trust worthiness to the answer.

Comment: Please be invited to submit edit suggestions to remove those where you find them.